# MOD_REWRITE - URL ENDING TRAILING SLASH

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ HTTP%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

ServerSignature Off

RewriteRule ^cookie-policy/?$ cookie_policy.php [NC,L]`
```

Hello I'm struggling really hard with URL closing trailing slash.

```
RewriteRule ^cookie-policy/?$ cookie_policy.php [NC,L]
```

I would like, for example, to force a redirection from `www.website.com/cookie-policy` to `www.website.com/cookie-policy/`

Comment: You already have a rule that adds a trailing slash.

Comment: It doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

It will add a `/` to end of your URLs. Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Thx for quick help, unfortunately it doesn't work.

[link](http://www.escortaltop.it/cookie-policy)